# Create customized NavigationTransitionInfo for Page Navigation Transitions in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, transition

I am working on a Universal Windows (UWP) app and I want to add some page NavigationTransitions to my pages . 
I know that I can use default NavigationThemeTransition like the code below :

```
<Page.Transitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
        <NavigationThemeTransition>
            <NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
                <CommonNavigationTransitionInfo/>
            </NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
        </NavigationThemeTransition>
    </TransitionCollection>
</Page.Transitions>
```

but I want to create my own Navigation Transition , I searched many times but no result . 
I also tried to get definitions of default navigations and I were able to write some code like below but don't know what I have to write in code blocks . Any help ?

```
  using Windows.UI.Xaml;
  using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation;
  using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;

  namespace BindingSample2
  {
    internal interface IWikiSedaNavigationTransitionInfo
    {
        System.Boolean IsStaggeringEnabled { get; set; }
    }
    public sealed class WikiSedaNavigationTransitionInfo : NavigationTransitionInfo, IWikiSedaNavigationTransitionInfo
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the WikiSedaNavigationTransitionInfo class.
        public WikiSedaNavigationTransitionInfo()
        {
            var a = this.GetNavigationStateCore();
            var s = this.MemberwiseClone();
            // NavigationThemeTransition theme = new NavigationThemeTransition();

            var themeR = new EdgeUIThemeTransition();

            themeR.Edge = EdgeTransitionLocation.Bottom;

            //Transitions = collection;
        }

        // Summary:
        //     Identifies the CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement attached property.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The identifier for the CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement attached
        //     property.
        public static DependencyProperty IsStaggerElementProperty { get; }

        // Summary:
        //     Identifies the IsStaggeringEnabled dependency property.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The identifier for the IsStaggeringEnabled dependency property.
        public static DependencyProperty IsStaggeringEnabledProperty { get; }

        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a Boolean value indicating if staggering is enabled for the navigation
        //     transition.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A Boolean value indicating if staggering is enabled for the navigation transition.
        public System.Boolean IsStaggeringEnabled { get; set; }

        // Summary:
        //     Returns a Boolean value indicating if the specified UIElement is the stagger
        //     element for the navigation transition.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   element:
        //     The UIElement to check as being the stagger element.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     Returns true if element is the stagger element; otherwise false.
        public static System.Boolean GetIsStaggerElement(UIElement element)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Summary:
        //     Sets a Boolean value indicating if the specified UIElement is the stagger element
        //     for the navigation transition.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   element:
        //     The UIElement about which to set the stagger element indicator.
        //
        //   value:
        //     Set this value to true if element is the stagger element; otherwise set it to
        //     false.
        public static void SetIsStaggerElement(UIElement element, System.Boolean value)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No one have any answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can achieve that in W10 Creators Update. Take a look at [this blog post](http://varunshandilya.com/create-custom-page-transitions-with-windows-creators-update/) I've just found [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/shandilvarun/status/846161590567256069).

Comment: Thanks . I will not make your reply as answer for possible other replies .But will mark as answer if no new answer coming

Comment: Ok, but it is still possible to add new answer even for already answered questions.

Comment: I didn't know that . Marked as answer

Comment: I will provide a note on this though, you will not be able to easily do this in XAML like you can currently. These aren't traditional transitions and use the newer Composition APIs. If you check out the source code in GitHub for the sample provided, you'll notice how complex it will be. 

As for your main question, you cannot do this and are limited to the transitions provided in the APIs.